# Save cv::Mat data for later usage using NO C++ constructs

Tags: c++, c, object, opencv, data-structures

I'm using OpenCV within a DLL that provides plain C interfaces, no C++objects are allowed to be handed over to the calling application.

One part of this DLL performs fiducial learning for later pattern recognition which results in a list of keypoints and a Mat object. These data have to be stored by the calling application.

Handing over the keypoints via DLL interface is no problem by using a plain C struct, the members of such a keypoint can be converted easily. But I don't see which parts of cv::Mat are really needed. Or to be more exact: my Mat-object makes use of the member "data" which points to a memory area but I have no idea how much data are contained.

So my question: how can I convert a cv::Mat object into a plain C-style structure, how can I estimate the exact length of the data field?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way is to convert cv::Mat to the classical OpenCV C structure: IplImage.

```
cv::Mat mat = imread(...);
IplImage img(mat); // hope it's the correct syntax...
```

A more detailed explanation of the Mat parameters:

- data: pointer to data
- rows, columns: ...
- type() - data type:
- channels() - number of channels
- step() - stride between two consecutive rows in the image, in bytes. "Includes the gaps, if any"
- size_t elemSize() similar to CV_ELEM_SIZE(cvmat->type)
- size_t elemSize1() returns the size of element channel in bytes.

And here's how you calculate data field length:

```
Mat::rows * Mat::step()
```

Comment: I'm ready to up vote this when you answer `how can I estimate the exact length of the data field?`

Comment: C'mon @karlphillip, is it that difficult to write a multiplication?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to pass a raw pointer to image data, then in the worst case you'll have to do some copying with pointer magic, because image data may not be continous. It is well described in [this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html).

```
int channels = I.channels();

int nRows = I.rows * channels;
int nCols = I.cols;

if (I.isContinuous())
{
    nCols *= nRows;
    nRows = 1;
}

int i,j;
uchar* p;
for( i = 0; i < nRows; ++i)
{
    p = I.ptr<uchar>(i);
    // And here "p" points to "nCols" components
    // row size = nCols * channels * component size (1 byte usually)
}
```